# Why does this cloning not work?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to clone instances of a derived class, but somehow it doesn't work well. The cloning method is:

```
public static T CloneFieldsAndProperties<T>(T input)
{
    T result = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    PropertyInfo[] listOfProps = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.CreateInstance);
    FieldInfo[] listOfFields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.CreateInstance);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in listOfProps) prop.SetValue(result, prop.GetValue(input, null), null);
    foreach (FieldInfo field in listOfFields) field.SetValue(result, field.GetValue(input));
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, I added many `BindingFlags` because it wasn't working. But to no avail.

It *does* work in a simple case:

```
MyclassA1 a1 = new MyclassA1();
MyclassA a = CloneFieldsAndProperties(a1);
if (a is MyclassA1) Text = "Works";
```

Where:

```
class MyclassA
{
    public int i;
}

class MyclassA1 : MyclassA
{
    public int i1;
}
```

But in my real program it doesn't. The real program's classes' declarations are long so I'm not posting them here. What might be the problem?

Comment: If it works in this simple case, perhaps the problem is somewhere in the code you say you are omitting?

Comment: @EliArbel That only creates a shallow copy. Not good in my case. But thanks.

Comment: @m-y I agree :) But what might it be? The code which has the problem is like in the simple one, but `(a is MyclassA1)` is false. The only real difference is the complexity of the classes.

Comment: @EliArbel Thanks. I didn't realize that. The objects _are_ actually Serializable (I save them to files). I just implemented that and it works fine.

Comment: @EliArbel Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm really wondering what in the complex case could have caused this sort of behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a shallow clone, simply use `Object.MemberwiseClone`. If you need a deep clone, serialize and then deserialize your object (e.g. using `JsonSerializer`).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue a long time ago. The only real solution for me, after lots of googling, was to serialize and deserialize it. It's not a bad solution and you lose only a little bit of performance, just do it like this:

Add this tag to your class:

```
[Serializable()]
public class a
{

}
```

And then you can create a function like this:

```
public object Clone()
{
    IO.MemoryStream mem = new IO.MemoryStream();
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter form = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
    form.Serialize(mem, this);
    mem.Position = 0;
    return form.Deserialize(mem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work and may be faster than the serialization method:

**Code:**

```
using System;

namespace Cloning
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Derived d = new Derived() { property = 1, field = 2, derivedProperty = 3, derivedField = 4 };
            Base b = new Derived(d);

            // Change things in the derived class.
            d.property = 5;
            d.field = 6;
            d.derivedProperty = 7;
            d.derivedField = 8;

            // Output the copy so you know it's not shallow.
            Console.WriteLine((b as Derived).property);
            Console.WriteLine((b as Derived).field);
            Console.WriteLine((b as Derived).derivedProperty);
            Console.WriteLine((b as Derived).derivedField);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class Base
        {
            public int property { get; set; }
            public int field;
        }

        class Derived : Base
        {
            public Derived() { }

            public Derived(Derived d)
            {
                // Perform the deep copy here.
                // Using reflection should work, but explicitly stating them definitely
                // will, and it's not like it's not all known until runtime.
                this.property = d.property;
                this.field = d.field;
                this.derivedProperty = d.derivedProperty;
                this.derivedField = d.derivedField;
            }

            public int derivedProperty { get; set; }
            public int derivedField;
        }

    }
}
```

**Test:**

http://goo.gl/pQnAL

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
```

**Comments:**

I would really imagine that this would work in more than just a trivial case but perhaps not:

```
public static T CloneFieldsAndProperties<T>(T input)
{
    T result = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(input.GetType());

    PropertyInfo[] properties = input.GetType().GetProperties();
    FieldInfo[] fields = input.GetType().GetFields();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        property.SetValue(result, property.GetValue(input, null), null);
    foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        field.SetValue(result, field.GetValue(input));

    return result;
}
```